# Xamarin Forms Android Emulator not attaching to debug

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin Forms using a shared project type. When I run the Android emulator in debug mode it will work properly once, but as soon as I make a code change, it does not attach to the code unless I delete the virtual device, re-create it and restart VS. 
Clearing the cache in the Android Emulator Manager does not work, neither does cleaning and rebuilding. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Solution:-

create text file and write below code in it :-

> FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S bin') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
>   FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S obj') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"

Now save this file with SamplefileName.bat with .bat extension.
Make sure while saving "select Save As Type" option as "All Files".

Now you need to place this .bat file into your Solution Directory where your project .SLN file resides.

This .bat file will delete the bin and obj folders from the project solution

Next step is now run this bat file whenever you make code changes and you want the debugger should work after the changes.

You may not need to close and reopen the emulator/ Genymotion vertual device